# Flexibility workouts for spinning heel kick - taekwondo

Tags: strength-training, flexibility, martial-arts

I am a taekwondo student (black belt) . I took a year long break, but have reconnected with the sport. Recently though, I learnt that I am unable to perform a spinning heel kick due to a lack of flexibility… my flexibility workouts are not helping… anyone know a good workout for this issue? I can perform all other kicks fine, struggling with just this one. If anyone has any strength workouts as well, then please share that as well. Thank you!

Comment: Which part of the kick are you having trouble with? Can't get the hip elevated? Can't turn over the hip? Just weak with the hit, or don't feel connected.

Answer (score 1):

One training method we use in Capoeira to improve spinning heel kick height (for us, it's titled *meia lua de compasso*) is to start in the back position, with the torso lowered (you can put your hands on the ground for support even if you don't usually do that for your kick) and just raise one leg up and down to get the position. Dynamically lifting it up and down will help not only in improving the flexibility, but also the muscles in your core and legs you need to lift it without being wholly dependent on momentum. For now, don't worry about turning your hip over, just raise it with your toes down. For now (again, not necessarily what you'll be doing with your kick), focus on getting your chest as close to the supporting leg as you can.

Once you can get your leg to the height you want, start doing the kick in a slow and controlled manner, thinking about the muscles you're using. Initially, your kick is going to be lower since you're not using momentum as much to carry yourself through. Honestly, hip-height is doing pretty good at first. Also, for this one, you will want to start turning your hip so that you're hitting with the heel. When you feel you've got it going smoothly, speed up the movement, but keep it consistent throughout. Again, you're working flexibility, but you're also building supporting muscles.

Lastly, look at technique. I don't know how granular they get at your school, but we have a step-by-step process for throwing the kick, starting with the initial position, working through when to release the leg, and torso posture as it swings back into place. We have a few general tips, but most of them may be specific to our style. First, starting with the kicking leg behind, as seems to be part of [the orthodox definition](https://taekwondo.fandom.com/wiki/Spinning_Heel_Kick), is good, because the other common way of teaching it, by stepping across sideways and into the kick, is more telegraphed, and will often result in people accidentally lifting the supporting leg (might be more peculiar to our style where the standard kick has hands planted). Second, as with the prior exercise, try to keep the speed consistent. A common mistake is doing the first part fast, and then trying to land slowly, which loses momentum. Third, try to avoid "chicken-winging" by letting the chest spread out. A common mistake has the side of the body toward the kick opening up during the kick, which bleeds momentum, which makes it harder to finish. Especially if you're doing the version with no hands on the ground, try to keep your arms in close to your torso as you're kicking and returning to stance. In my experience, the one-hand support is particularly prone to this, as it feels natural to keep the off hand down while kicking, but it will leave you in a compromised position where it will be hard to lift your torso again.

I wish I could give you more regular exercises rather than kicking ones, but honestly, other than the leg lifts to the back, the best way of training the kick is to do it in a controlled manner.